# How to fetch data dynamically from web server?

Tags: java, web-services, mongodb, servlets

I have a Mongodb database that contains a Poll Collection.
The Poll collection has a number of Poll documents. This could be a large number of documents.

I am using Java Servlet for serving HTTP requests.

How can I implement a feed kind of retrieval mechanism at the server side?
For e.g., In the first request, I want to retrieve 1 to 10, documents, then 11 to 20 and so on...
As there is a scroll in the view, i want to get the data from server and send to client.

Does Mongodb provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a pagination. You could use the limit and skip methods with your find query.

```
First request
db.Poll.find().skip(0).limit(10)

Second request
db.Poll.find().skip(10).limit(10)
...
...
```

Note: You should also be sorting your find with some field.

```
db.Poll.find().skip(10).limit(10).sort({_id:-1})
```

For more info on the cursor methods you could look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/

Comment: Thanks :) So, does the cursor, not fetch of all the documents in a collection? Also, sorting each time would probably be time consuming? Is there a better approach?

Comment: No, the cursor will not fetch all the documents. If you do not sort then you might not get data in correct order. If the query takes lot of time then try adding an index.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lalit, your answer is really helpful.

Comment: What would be the best way to sort, if I need the latest first. I mean the latest added document. Can you explain with some snipped please. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a date created field then you could sort it with it or you could sort with _id as it contains timestamp assuming you are using ObjectId in _id field.